# I am using db forge for database migration.add_foreign_key add keys from first created table to second one

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-migration

I am using db forge for  database migration in ci.When I add foreign key in first created table. It works but in second table foreign key from first table inherit so it create problem to create the sencond table. Here is  my code

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Initial_schema {
    function up() 
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        if($CI->migrate->verbose)
            echo "Creating tables...";
        // create table TblRowStatusEnum
        if(! $CI->db->table_exists('TblRowStatusEnum')) {
            $cols = array(
                'id' => array('type' => 'INT', 'constraint' => 11, 'auto_increment' => TRUE,'null'=>FALSE),
                'status' => array('type' => 'enum("Active","Inactive","Delete")', 'null' => FALSE),
                'description' => array('type' => 'VARCHAR', 'constraint' => '200', 'null' => True),
                'createdAt' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => FALSE),
                'updatedAt' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => TRUE)

            );

            // Setup Keys
            $CI->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
            $CI->dbforge->add_field($cols);
            $CI->dbforge->create_table('TblRowStatusEnum', TRUE);

            //insert data
            /*$insert = array('status' => 'Active','description' =>'Active');
            $CI->db->insert('TblRowStatusEnum', $insert);
            $insert = array('status' => 'Inactive','description' =>'Inactive');
            $CI->db->insert('TblRowStatusEnum', $insert);
            $insert = array('status' => 'Delete','description' =>'Delete');
            $CI->db->insert('TblRowStatusEnum', $insert);*/

    }

    // create table TblUser
    if(! $CI->db->table_exists('TblUser')) {
        $cols = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'INT', 'constraint' => 11,'auto_increment' => TRUE,'null'=>FALSE),
        'facebookId' => array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => '11', 'null' => FALSE),
        'firstName' => array('type' => 'VARCHAR','constraint' => '255', 'null' => FALSE),
        'middleName' => array('type' => 'VARCHAR','constraint' => '255', 'null' => TRUE),
        'lastName' => array('type' => 'VARCHAR','constraint' => '255', 'null' => FALSE),
        'email' => array('type' => 'VARCHAR','constraint' => '255', 'null' => FALSE),
        'address' => array('type' => 'TEXT'),
        'dateOfBirth' => array('type' => 'DATE'),
        'facebookAuthToken' => array('type' => 'TEXT', 'null' => FALSE ,'comment'=>"For storing auth token for offline access. If we don''t need offline access this column can be deleted"),
        'profileImageUrl' => array('type' => 'TEXT','null' => FALSE),
        'rowStatus' => array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => '11','null' => FALSE),
        'createdAt' => array('type' => 'DATETIME', 'null' => FALSE),
        'updatedAt' => array('type' => 'DATETIME', 'null' => TRUE)
        );

        // Setup Keys
        $CI->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
        $CI->dbforge->add_key('rowStatus');
        $CI->dbforge->add_field($cols);




        //gives CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY `fk_testTable_testField` (`myField`)
        //      REFERENCES testTable(`testField`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

        $CI->dbforge->add_foreign_key(array('field' => 'rowStatus',
        'foreign_table' => 'TblRowStatusEnum',
        'foreign_field' => 'id'));
        $CI->dbforge->create_table('TblUser', TRUE);
    }

    //TblSellingItem
    if(! $CI->db->table_exists('TblSellingItem')) {
        $cols = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'INT', 'constraint' => 11,'auto_increment' => TRUE,'null'=>FALSE),
        'title' => array('type' => 'VARCHAR','constraint' => '255', 'null' => FALSE),
        'description' => array('type' => 'TEXT'),
        'price' => array('type' => 'FLOAT','null' => FALSE),
        'postedBy' => array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => 11,'null' => FALSE),
        'rowStatus' => array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => 11,'null' => FALSE),
        'createdAt' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => FALSE,'default'=>get_now()),
        'updatedAt' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => TRUE)

        );

        // Setup Keys
        $CI->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
        $CI->dbforge->add_key('postedBy');
        $CI->dbforge->add_key('rowStatus');
        $CI->dbforge->add_field($cols);
        $CI->dbforge->add_foreign_key(array('field' => 'rowStatus',
           'foreign_table' => 'TblRowStatusEnum',
           'foreign_field' => 'id'));
       $CI->dbforge->add_foreign_key(array('field' => 'postedBy',
       'foreign_table' => 'TblUser',
       'foreign_field' => 'id'));
        $CI->dbforge->create_table('TblSellingItem', TRUE);


    }

    //TblItemImage
    if(! $CI->db->table_exists('TblItemImage')) {
        $cols = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'INT', 'constraint' => 11, 'auto_increment' => TRUE,'null'=>FALSE),
        'sellingItemId' => array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => '11', 'null' => FALSE),
        'url' => array('type' => 'TEXT','null' => FALSE),
        'imageOrder' => array('type' => 'INT','null' => FALSE),
        'rowStatus' => array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => 11,'null' => FALSE),
        'createdAt' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => FALSE,'default'=>get_now()),
        'updatedAt' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => TRUE)

        );

        // Setup Keys
        $status =array('field' => 'rowStatus',
        'foreign_table' => 'TblRowStatusEnum',
        'foreign_field' => 'id');
        $posted_by =array('field' => 'sellingItemId',
        'foreign_table' => 'TblSellingItem',
        'foreign_field' => 'id');
        $CI->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
        $CI->dbforge->add_key('sellingItemId');
        $CI->dbforge->add_key('rowStatus');
        $CI->dbforge->add_field($cols);
        $CI->dbforge->add_foreign_key($status);
        $CI->dbforge->add_foreign_key($posted_by);
        $CI->dbforge->create_table('TblItemImage', TRUE);



    }


    //TblChatMessage
    if(! $CI->db->table_exists('TblChatMessage')) {

    $cols = array(
    'id' => array('type' => 'INT', 'constraint' => 11, 'auto_increment' => TRUE,'null'=>FALSE),
    'sellingItemId' => array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => '11', 'null' => FALSE),
    'message' => array('type' => 'TEXT'),
    'sender' => array('type' => 'INT','null' => FALSE),
    'receiver' => array('type' => 'INT','null' => FALSE),
    'sentTime' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => FALSE),
    'messageStatus' => array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => 11,'null' => FALSE),
    'rowStatus' => array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => 11,'null' => FALSE),
    'createdAt' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => FALSE,'default'=>get_now()),
    'updatedAt' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => TRUE)

    );

    // Setup Keys
    $CI->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
    $CI->dbforge->add_key('sellingItemId');
    $CI->dbforge->add_key('sender');
    $CI->dbforge->add_key('receiver');
    $CI->dbforge->add_key('rowStatus');
    $CI->dbforge->add_field($cols);

    $CI->dbforge->add_foreign_key(array('field' => 'rowStatus',
    'foreign_table' => 'TblRowStatusEnum',
    'foreign_field' => 'id'));
    $CI->dbforge->add_foreign_key(array('field' => 'sellingItemId',
    'foreign_table' => 'TblSellingItem',
    'foreign_field' => 'id'));
    $CI->dbforge->add_foreign_key(array('field' => 'receiver',
    'foreign_table' => 'TblUser',
    'foreign_field' => 'id'));
    $CI->dbforge->add_foreign_key(array('field' => 'sender',
    'foreign_table' => 'TblUser',
    'foreign_field' => 'id'));

    $CI->dbforge->create_table('TblChatMessage', TRUE);





    }


    }

    function down() 
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        if($CI->migrate->verbose)
        echo "Dropping table accounts...";
        $CI->dbforge->drop_table('TblRowStatusEnum');
    }
}

?>
```

Error is like this

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1072

Key column 'postedBy' doesn't exist in table

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TblItemImage` ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`sellingItemId` INT(11) NOT NULL, `url` TEXT NOT NULL, `imageOrder` INT NOT NULL, 
`rowStatus` INT(11) NOT NULL, `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT '2014-03-19 11:51:13' NOT NULL, 
`updatedAt` datetime NULL, PRIMARY KEY `id` (`id`), FOREIGN KEY `rowStatus` (`rowStatus`) 
REFERENCES `TblRowStatusEnum`(`id`), FOREIGN KEY `rowStatus` (`rowStatus`) REFERENCES 
`TblRowStatusEnum`(`id`), FOREIGN KEY `postedBy` (`postedBy`) REFERENCES `TblUser`(`id`), 
FOREIGN KEY `rowStatus` (`rowStatus`) REFERENCES `TblRowStatusEnum`(`id`), FOREIGN KEY 
`sellingItemId` (`sellingItemId`) REFERENCES `TblSellingItem`(`id`), KEY `sellingItemId` 
(`sellingItemId`), KEY `rowStatus` (`rowStatus`) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\plunder_migration\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

here FOREIGN KEY `postedBy` is add automatically in table TblItemImage. what is wrong with my code? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make a test by changing the constraint postedBy by the following code and give us the result?

```
postedBy' => array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => 11,'null' => TRUE),
```